# Is it possible to modify the error response of marshmallow

Tags: python, marshmallow

Marshmallow gives a default error response of

```
"test_field": [
    "is a required field"
]
```

is it possible to modify the response in order to achieve

```
"test_field": [
    {
        new_field: 'error value',
        err_message: 'is a required field'
    }
]
```

I haven't seen any example on docs, any idea on how can I achieve that?

Comment: Does this help? https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending.html#custom-error-handling

Comment: @MichaelRuth while I'm sure that you've pointed OP in the right direction it is worth noting that passing a dict to `error_messages` field param changes the behavior so that the error isn't wrapped in a list as in the OPs example. E.g., `test_field=fields.String(..., error_messages={"new_field": ...})` renders the error like `'test_field': {'new_field': 'whatever', 'err_message': 'is a required field'}`. Not to mention that field error messages are typed `Dict[str, str]`, e.g., https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/1636.